# Is it possible to allow passing arguments as references without breaking referential transparency in functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming

Referential transparency is a relatively new concept to me, but I understood that it means that a function will always give the same answer given the same arguments.

Would passing arguments by reference break this property somehow in a functional language?

Comment: DId you have something other in mind than "make all data immutable"?

Comment: Yes, something like passing a variable as reference but consider it a const only in function's scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to observe a difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference would be to mutate the reference. But, since referential transparency precludes mutation, that is not possible.

So, in other words: in a functional language, it is actually impossible to tell the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. As a consequence, the language implementor is free to choose either, or maybe even both, depending on performance, personal preference, ease of implementation, or really any criteria they want.